# How to add new line inside a <p> tag in html when using Django to pass data?

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I have model of Players in Django which looks like this:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, default='')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
```

I pass the Player objects in the context:

```
def playerView(request):
    players = Player.objects.all()
    context = {'players':players}
    return render(request, 'base/players.html', context)
```

Now, I render the description in p tag of html using below code:

players.html

```
{% for player in players %}
<p>{{player.name}}</p>
<p>{{player.description}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But when I try to add description with newlines in it like:

```
This is line one.
This is line two.
```

It renders data like this:

```
This is line one.This is line two.
```

I tried adding &#13 &#10 which I found in one of the answers is a new line character, but it doesn't work. I also tried adding \n  and also tried adding br tag, but that also didn't work. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on django docs I think [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) template tag can help you

```
<p>{{player.description|linebreaks}}</p>
```

Or use `<pre`